# How to import csv file with the index column being "date" using Tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I want to import a csv file using Tkinter.

I have the following piece of code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("KLBJ2.csv",
                      header=0,
                      index_col='Date of removal',
                      parse_dates=True)

df = df[['Price']]
```

I can't seem to comprehend how I would transform this piece of code to something that uses a Tkinter button that imports csv files with the index_col being the date and then using the data in that CSV file to save in variables.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
df=pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False, header=0,
index_col='Date of removal',
parse_dates=True)
```

this lets me open any excel file I want!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback method on button click which will invoke the above piece of code. Sample code will look something like this.

```
b = Button(self, text="import csv", anchor = NW, relief=RAISED)
b.configure(command=self.import_csv_fun, width=8, activebackground="#33B5E5")

def import_csv_fun(self, widget):
    """imports the csv file"""
    df = pd.read_csv("KLBJ2.csv",
                      header=0,
                      index_col='Date of removal',
                      parse_dates=True)

    df = df[['Price']]
```

You can manipulate the `df` the way you want!

Comment: correct this lets you import a predefined csv, I was wondering how to import yet another csv aside from the predefined one.